# Can we use react-pdf in Next.js server action?

Tags: next.js, react-pdf

Can we use [React-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/) to generate PDF in Next.js 13.5.4 server action?

I create a server action like the following,

```
"use server";
import React from "react";
import { Page, Text, Document, renderToBuffer } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

const MyDocument = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page>
      <Text>React-pdf</Text>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);

export const createPdf = async () => {
  await renderToBuffer(<MyDocument />);
};
```

then I'm calling this server action on client component,

```
const onSubmit: = async (data) => {
  await createPdf();
};
```

but it will throw the this error:

```
 ⨯ node_modules\@react-pdf\renderer\lib\react-pdf.cjs.js (719:9) @ $$$reconciler
 ⨯ TypeError: ba.Component is not a constructor
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

add to your next-config:

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['@react-pdf/renderer'],
  }
};
```

see https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverComponentsExternalPackages

and https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/2350#issuecomment-1914234934